# How can I determine the type of a blessed reference in Perl?

Tags: perl, reference, types

In Perl, an object is just a reference to any of the basic Perl data types that has been blessed into a particular class.  When you use the ref() function on an unblessed reference, you are told what data type the reference points to.  However, when you call ref() on a blessed reference, you are returned the name of the package that reference has been blessed into.

I want to know the actual underlying type of the blessed reference.  How can I determine this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Scalar::Util::reftype()` is the cleanest solution. The [`Scalar::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Scalar-List-Utils/lib/Scalar/Util.pm) module was added to the Perl core in version 5.7 but is available for older versions (5.004 or later) from CPAN.

You can also probe with `UNIVERSAL::isa()`:

```
$x->isa('HASH')             # if $x is known to be an object
UNIVERSAL::isa($x, 'HASH')  # if $x might not be an object or reference
```

Obviously, you'd also have to check for `ARRAY` and `SCALAR` types. The UNIVERSAL module (which serves as the base class for all objects) has been part of the core since Perl 5.003.

Another way -- easy but a little dirty -- is to stringify the reference. Assuming that the class hasn't overloaded stringification you'll get back something resembling `Class=HASH(0x1234ABCD)`, which you can parse to extract the underlying data type:

```
my $type = ($object =~ /=(.+)\(0x[0-9a-f]+\)$/i);
```

Comment: You just want eval { $x->isa($type) }; If that's not an object, you get back false. If it's not the right type, you get false, and if it is the right type, you get true.  :)

Answer (score 6):

You probably shouldn't do this. The underlying type of an object is an implementation detail you shouldn't mess with. Why would you want to know this?

Comment: Agreed, and I knew somebody would make this comment.  I really only needed this while trying to figure out a structure a module was creating so I could modify the module.  I wanted to delete a particular key from any hashes in the structure because they contained a raw JPEG.

Comment: Later I discovered that I could use Data::Dumper::sortkeys to filter this data so Data::Dumper didn't produce megabytes of binary output.

Answer (score 2):

And my first thought on this was: "Objects in Perl are always hash refs, so what the hack?"

But, Scalar::Util::reftype is the answer. Thanks for putting the question here.

Here is a code snippet to prove this.. (in case it is of any use to anyone).

```
$> perl -e 'use strict; use warnings "all";
            my $x = [1]; bless ($x, "ABC::Def");
            use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $x;
            print ref($x) . "\n";
            use Scalar::Util "reftype"; print reftype($x) . "\n"'`
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = bless( [
                 1
               ], 'ABC::Def' );
ABC::Def
ARRAY
```

Comment: Objects are often implemented as hash references, but it's not a requirement. An object can be any reference type.