# How do I get the type of a blessed ref? (ARRAY|HASH|SCALAR)

Tags: perl

I'm passed a reference, and I want to know its type. For this purpose,
"ref" works on unblessed references, but on blessed references it returns
the package name it was blessed with.

```
     $a=[];
     print ref $a;
```

> ARRAY

```
     bless $a, 'mytype';
     print ref $a;
```

> mytype

How can I get the type?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085/how-can-i-determine-the-type-of-a-blessed-reference-in-perl

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
use Scalar::Util 'reftype';
print reftype bless {}; # HASH
```

Comment: pedantically, use Scalar::Util 1.01 'reftype';   since reftype was added less than 10 years ago, some poor souls may be lacking it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Scalar::Util::reftype for this, but in general it isn't something that you need to do.  Usually people asking this question indicates they are doing something else in a less than ideal way.  So, why do you think you need to know?

Comment: It's true.  Once you bless something, you shouldn't access the underlying data directly.  (Sometimes it's useful to do anyway, though, if you are Data::Dumper or Data::Visitor or something.)

Comment: I know what I'm doing; namely, implementing something akin to Data::Dumper but into a specific format.

Comment: You should implement a dump() method on the object that you can call, which will do Data::Dumper-like activities and keep the type-aware code locked inside the module.

Comment: No, he should use Data::Visitor.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment above.. you are incorrect if you think that external code needs to be aware of the implementation details of a blessed object.  If you need to do something like Data::Dumper on the object, create a dump() method on the module which contains the implementation logic.  You could add some code into the UNIVERSAL class's autoloader so that it just calls Data::Dumper if you attempt to call dump() on an object that doesn't define it.