# perl adds dummy elements to array after inquiry

Tags: perl

As the title says, perl adds dummy elements to arrays after inquiries to not existing elements. Array size grows after the inquiry.  Illustration to the behaviour:

```
    my $rarr;
    $rarr->[0][0] = 'S';
    $rarr->[0][1] = 'MD';
    $rarr->[1][0] = 'S';
    $rarr->[1][1] = 'PRP';

    my $crulesref;
    $crulesref->[0]  = $rarr;

     check_rule('aa', 0);
     if($rarr->[3][0] == 'M'){  # just check a not existing element
        print "m\n";   
     }

     check_rule('bb', 0);
     if($rarr->[5][0] == 'M'){  # again: just check a not existing element
        print "m\n";
     }
     check_rule('cc', 0);


     sub check_rule($$)
     {
         my ($strg,$ix) = @_;
         my $aref = $crulesref->[$ix];
         my $rule_size = @$aref;
         {print "-----$strg aref:$aref rs:$rule_size aref:'@$aref'\n";
           for(my $t1 = 0; $t1 <$rule_size; $t1++){
             print "t1:$t1 0:$aref->[$t1][0] 1:$aref->[$t1][1]\n";
           }
         }
       }
```

The result of the run is:

```
    en@en-desktop ~/dtest/perl/forditas/utf8_v1/forditas/test1 $ perl v15.pl
    -----aa aref:ARRAY(0x90ed8c8) rs:2 aref:'ARRAY(0x9106cac) ARRAY(0x9106d24)'
    t1:0 0:S 1:MD
    t1:1 0:S 1:PRP
    m                     <-------------- finds the non existing
    -----bb aref:ARRAY(0x90ed8c8) rs:4 aref:'ARRAY(0x9106cac) ARRAY(0x9106d24)          ARRAY(0x9107508)'
    t1:0 0:S 1:MD
    t1:1 0:S 1:PRP
    t1:2 0: 1:               <-- undesired dummy due to inquiry
    t1:3 0: 1:               <-- undesired dummy due to inquiry
    m                      <-------------- finds the non existing
    -----cc aref:ARRAY(0x90ed8c8) rs:6 aref:'ARRAY(0x9106cac) ARRAY(0x9106d24) ARRAY(0x9107904) ARRAY(0x9107508)  ARRAY(0x910e860)'
    t1:0 0:S 1:MD
    t1:1 0:S 1:PRP
    t1:2 0: 1:               <-- undesired dummy due to inquiry
    t1:3 0: 1:               <-- undesired dummy due to inquiry
    t1:4 0: 1:               <-- undesired dummy due to inquiry
    t1:5 0: 1:               <-- undesired dummy due to inquiry
```

Is there no other way to avoid this than to ask before each inquiry, if the inquired element exists? I try to increase speed, and these inquiries slow the code down, and make it less easy to read.

Thanks in advance for useful hints.

Comment: Finding not existing comes from bad inquiry. Instead of == one must use eq. However, this is not the main problem. The main problim is the adding of elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) that you are seeing. If you access the memory of `$ref->[3][0]` even with just a check:

```
if ($ref->[3][0] eq 'M' )
```

Then first `$ref->[3]` must exist before its element number zero can be checked, so it is created via autovivification. You need to first check if `$ref->[3]` exists or is defined to avoid creating it.

```
if (defined($ref->[3]) && $ref->[3][0] eq 'M')
```

Also, you should always use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Then you would see the warnings

```
Argument "M" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ...
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ...
```

The if-clause gives a false positive here because the string `'M'` is converted to a number (`0`) because of the context imposed by the numeric equality operator `==`. The LHS value is `undef`, which is also converted to a number (`0`), which is why the expression evaluates to true.

Comment: `if ($ref->[3] && $ref->[3][0] eq 'M')` would suffice

Comment: @ikegami Yes, but for the sake of demonstration, it is perhaps a good idea to be specific.

Comment: If you _really_ wanted to be specific, surely that should be `if (ref($ref->[3]) eq 'ARRAY' && $ref->[3][0] eq 'M')`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen `bless {}, 'ARRAY'`

Comment: @ysth: ... *why* would you even...? o_O \*head hurts\* But OK, [fine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11085), make that `use Scalar::Util qw(reftype); if (reftype($ref->[3]) eq 'ARRAY' && $ref->[3][0] eq 'M')` then.

Comment: Thanks, autovivification is an interesting feature. I now check everywhere with defined(...) before inquiry.

Comment: @eleonora Be sure to also use strict and warnings, they are very helpful. If this solved your problem, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: @TLP   Yes, the question is perfectly answered.

Comment: How can I mark this answer as accepted? I only see active, oldest and vote besides the word 'Answers'.

Comment: I have clicked the checked sign below answer, and it became green. Thank you for your answer.