# How is the scalar $keys getting value 1 instead of undef?

Tags: perl, key, exists

Folks,

As far as my understanding goes, `exists` function would check for existence of a key in a hash. So for the below mentioned situation, `key1` or `key2` have not been defined. Going by that the hash reference `$var` has no keys.

In which case upon calling `keys(%{$var})`  should return undef.

HOWEVER, its returning 1. How..what am I missing here ?

```
my $var;
if (exists $var->{key1}->{key2}) {
    $var->{key1}->{key2} = 1;
}

my $keys = keys(%{$var});

print $keys;   #prints 1 to output console
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/14803604/725418

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you're checking $var->{key1}->{key2} creates $var->{key1} as empty hashref. This can be seen by doing:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $var = {};
if (exists $var->{key1}->{key2}) {
    print "cannot happen\n"
}
print Dumper($var);
```

Which prints:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key1' => {}
        };
```

So, the scalar of keys is 1, because there is one key.

Comment: Thanks. I always miss the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

This is [autovivification](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#A). Note that you can disable autovivification for your whole script, or for a particular lexical scope, by using the [no autovification;](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/autovivification-0.11/lib/autovivification.pm) pragma.